# how to hide querystring in asp.net content page?

Tags: string, hide

i have master-content page scenario.I have a link button on content page. that redirects to other page. but with redirection it carrying the parameters. I want to hide this querystring parameters .I tried with POST() in Form tag of master page  . but that does not affecting. What have to do ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many ways to carry values from one page to the next. You could store the values in some Session type container, or add them as hidden fields.

If you want a ugly way, you could use a good old frameset.

Comment: I am agree with you , but i have inline html code . that code have the href. I set some parameters as querystring to href. please ..help me

Answer (score 0):

POST is the answer, but we'll need some code to help more effectively